# Host-only network with Ubuntu guest in VirtualBox with Host running a Juniper VPN

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Windows host that needs to run a Juniper VPN, and an Ubuntu guest that needs to be accessible from the host as it runs a web server that must be accessed by the host.

Without the VPN running I just use a Host-Only adapter and I can access the guest from the host and viceversa without any issue. However, once I open the VPN client in the host, this stops working. I've tried with the other networking options that Virtualbox supplies to no avail.

Can somebody tell me how to configure the network adapters so that this communication is posible? It would be great if communication can be 2-way.

Answer (score 0):

this is usually because VPN gets the highest order on the set of routes, and VPN isn't interested in your server IP address. You need to add a route to your host for the IP address for your server. Check out [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/247852/rerouting-local-lan-and-internet-traffic-when-in-vpn) from SuperUser for more information.