# How to enable local LAN access while connected to Array VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, ssl-vpn

I am trying to maintain a local LAN service (allow incoming connections from my local network) on a Windows machine while connecting to Array SSL VPN.

I've tried to modify the route table using some methods like [Rerouting local LAN and Internet traffic when in VPN](https://superuser.com/questions/247852/rerouting-local-lan-and-internet-traffic-when-in-vpn) . There are 2 entries concerning my local network:

```
Destination     Netmask        Gateway       Interface       Metric 
172.16.0.0      255.255.0.0    172.16.3.10   172.16.3.10      10
172.16.0.0      255.255.0.0    10.1.0.1       10.1.0.11       1
```

(My local network uses 172.16.0.0/16 and the VPN network uses 10.0.0.0/8)
I think maybe these rules caused blocking of local incoming connection. But the route command(delete,change or add) doesn't take effect on these records. It seems these two records are locked.

After searching, I know if there are some related settings in the VPN client, the name may be "tunnel splitting" or "local LAN access". I exported the setting and found an entry calls `Local_Subnet_Access`, I've tried to change it to be `172.16.0.0/16` or `1`, then import the config and restart. But the problem still persists.

I have no I idea how to config now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your LAN has 172.16.0.0/16 you will have the network default route like shown above, but the second rule looks strange. It means that all your local traffic will be redirected to the VPN tunnel.
Can you look for VPN config to see something like 'add default gateway'?
Or post the output of the 'route print' before VPN connected and after.

All you need to do is add 0.0.0.0/0 route with metric=2 and VPN gateway, to be sure that all traffic except local will go to VPN gateway.